# How to find all possible combinations of dictionary values that add up to a certain number in Python while still retaining the key names

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with fields having pre-assigned scores.  For example, FirstNM has a score of 300. Here is a sample dictionary:

```
my_dictionary = dict()
my_dictionary['FirstNM'] = 300
my_dictionary['LastNM'] = 500
my_dictionary['MiddlNM'] = 700

print(my_dictionary)

{'FirstNM': 300, 'LastNM': 500, 'MiddleNM': 700}
```

I need to find all possible combinations of dictionary values that sum up to more than 900.

I used this code to find all the possible combinations:

```
values = my_dictionary.values()
keys = my_dictionary.keys()

result = [seq for i in range(len(values), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(values, i) if sum(seq) >= 900]

print(result)

[(300, 500, 700), (300, 700), (500, 700)]
```

How do I then re-assign the keys to the values?  I've looked all over and can't make heads or tails of how to do this...Ultimately, I'd like the keys that are in the groups and not the values.  Any help is much appreciated.

Desired Result:

```
[('FirstNM', 'LastNM', 'MiddlNM'), ('FirstNM', 'LastNM'), ('LastNM', 'MiddlNM')]
```

Comment: Do you want to print the key instead of the values for the result?

Comment: Please add the desired result to the question.

Comment: @Tim, yeah, just made an edit to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the keys instead of the values and map them to their values for the sum test:

```
result = [seq for i in range(len(values), 0, -1)
              for seq in itertools.combinations(keys, i)
              if sum(map(my_dictionary.get,seq)) >= 900]

print(result)
[('FirstNM', 'LastNM', 'MiddlNM'), ('FirstNM', 'MiddlNM'), ('LastNM', 'MiddlNM')]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you!